# Running script inside a textarea to print a value

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Well the question is quite simple, How can I run the `<script>` tags inside a textarea so that I can use `document.write` to print out a value?

Like:

```
<textarea>
    <script>
        document.write("A");
    </script>
</textarea>
```

Doing this would just print out `<script>document.write("A");</script>` into the textarea.

See here: <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/e4gA3/)</kbd>

But I want to print A inside the textarea how can I do that?

Comment: give some id to textarea and then use innerHTML.

Comment: Can't I achieve that my way?

Comment: Why are you putting code inside of a `textarea` in the first place?  This seems to have "bad idea" written all over it...

Comment: @David OP is most likely asking because he was hoping to use it for an XSS attack. (Hopefully for a legal penetration test.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place a script (or any other) element in a textarea, it's content model [is defined as](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-textarea-element) *text*.

The only way to generate the content of a textarea using `document.write` is to generate the entire textarea (including the start and end tags) using that method.

Comment: So is that not possible my way?

Comment: Correct. You can't put a script in a textarea.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e4gA3/1/) it is.

```
<textarea id="textMy"></textarea>
document.getElementById("textMy").innerHTML = 'A'
```

You miss the point of how JS works. You can not place it inside of some element hoping that it will print it inside of this element. You need to get that element and then modify it's properties somehow.